# Linear Layout, Android Xamarin,

Tags: layout, xamarin.android, design

Una duda con el diseño de android, quiero poner en un renglón 6 controles, 3 TextView y 3 EditText, y ahí todo bien, pero abajo de esos controles digamos un "reglón abajo" quiero poner otros 6 controles similares, pero con los de abajo, pero cuando intento ponerlos, como que se sobreponen a los otros 6
Alguna idea, o algún material de documentación para saber como funcionan los layouts y demás controles de android necesarios para el diseño, apenas voy empezando con Android
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblEstilo"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Estilo"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtEstilo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@drawable/EditTextColorBorder"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblColor"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Color"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtColor"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@drawable/EditTextColorBorder"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblAcabado"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Acabado"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAcabado"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@drawable/EditTextColorBorder"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer linearLayout debe colocarse con orientacion vertical

Comment: Cierto, muchas gracias, no me había fijado en eso ;)